# sprite vs individual images

Tags: html, css-sprites, sprite, sprite-sheet

Ok - for a web SITE that loads over and over again this is an obvious question. One sprite sheet (that will probably be cached on the users system) and some fancy css background-position trickery, and you're saving yourself a ton of server requests.

But for a web APP, that loads once, and never again. Is a sprite really the way to go. Yes, breaking it up into individual pngs means that many more requests up front, but in the long run, how does this fair?

I'm guessing it depends entirely on the rendering engine and how the memory management works, but it seems like having a 200k sprite sheet duplicated all over the place might be more costly to performance in the long run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you will use sprite for change states of particular element, e.g. for the button, not for all the images at once. Benefit of using sprites in that case is not just to save a request, but also to make state changes (say on mouse over) instant.